# how to amend the disconnected line to a successive line in the grayed pic by openvc？

Tags: python, opencv

I used `OpenCv` to handle a RGB picture and get it's red trace .Because of some trace cross black area, some trace is disconnected.I want to amend the disconnected line.

I try `cv2.dilate` to enlarge the trace.But if it lost to much, i should do make the trace more larger and it will destroy other trace which is near.

```
def get_trace_list(img, debug=False):
    """
    :param img:
    :return:
    """
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_red = np.array([0, 5, 150])
    upper_red = np.array([8, 210, 255])
    mask0 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

    lower = np.array([150, 5, 150])
    upper = np.array([180, 210, 255])
    mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

    mask = mask0 + mask1

    only_red_color = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

    _, red_color_fix = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(only_red_color, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
    dilated = cv2.dilate(cv2.medianBlur(red_color_fix, 3), kernel, iterations=9)
    cv2.imshow('dilated', dilated)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    check_imgs = []
    for index, contour in enumerate(contours):
        con_len = cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
        if con_len > 200:
            [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
            check_imgs.append(red_color_fix[y:y+h, x:x+w])
            if debug:
                cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 255), 2)
                cv2.imwrite('./questions/%s.png' % index, red_color_fix[y:y+h, x:x+w])
    if debug:
        cv2.imwrite('./questions/question.png' , img)
    return check_imgs
```

[image: picture after dilated]

[image: picture trace area]